# Иконка для кнопки Floating Action Button

Tags: android, button

Подскажите, как для кнопки Floating Action Button правильно сделать иконку в виде знака "+". Вроде это стандартная штука и часто видел его в разных приложениях, но в готовых иконках не нашел его.

**Вопрос:**
1) Как его найти и назначить кнопке, если он все же где-то есть?
2) Если стандартной иконки нет, то как его делают другие разработчики? Просто рисуют на глаз?

В инструкции по [материал дизайн кнопок](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types) этот "+" нарисован на кнопке fab, хочу именно такой же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается все стандартные иконки уже есть в *Android Studio*.

Для **добавления иконки**, на папке "*res*" жмем правую кнопку мыши. Выбираем "*New - Image Asset*". Находим нужную иконку в галерее иконок. Указываем название, выбираем цвет, ставим прозрачность фона. Жмем "*Далее*" и "*Ок*".

Выбранная иконка добавится в папку "*mipmap*" сразу в нескольких размерах. Нужная будет подставляться автоматически в зависимости от плотности экрана устройства.

Подключение иконки для *fab* кнопки делаем так:

```
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/название_иконки"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Заходите на сайт https://material.io/icons/ , находите нужную вам иконку.
2. Добавляете в `drawable` своего проекта.
3. В разметке `fab` добавляете строчку `android:src="@drawable/<название вашей иконки>"`

Comment: Спасибо, но нашел более удобный способ ).